# Redraw morris graph in jQuery after post .NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have written a following code in my .NET Controller action which fetches specific time zone. After that I Group by the data based on that time zone like following:

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("FetchTimeZone")]
        public ActionResult FetchTimeZone(string timeZone)
        {
            using (var ctx = new myContext())
            {
                var loggedUser = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == User.Identity.Name);
                var userStores = ctx.UserStores.Where(x => x.UserId == loggedUser.UserId).SelectMany(x => x.StoreItems.SelectMany(y => y.StoreItemTransactions)).ToList();
                var hourlyData = userStores
                .GroupBy(x => TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(x.TransactionDate.Value, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Tokyo Standard Time")).Hour)
                .Select(pr => new HourlyGraph { Hour = pr.Key, Sales = pr.Sum(x => x.QuantitySoldTransaction) })
                .ToList();
                hourlyData.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0, 24)
                .Except(hourlyData.Select(m => m.Hour))
                .Select(i => new HourlyGraph() { Hour = i, Sales = 0 }));
                ViewBag.HourlyGraph = hourlyData.OrderBy(x => x.Hour).ToList();
                return Json("OK");

            }
        }
```

All here is good, so we move on to the View part with jQuery and data representation.. Initially when the page is loaded I fill graph with CEST time zone and it represents the data correctly. So I made an on click event which basically should redraw the morris graph based on the time zone that was sent.

By default I set in code Tokyo Standard Time just to get different results to verify whether this works or not. So initially I fill the graph like this:

```
var hourlyGraph = Morris.Bar({
            element: 'graph_bar',
            data: [
               @foreach (var item in ViewBag.HourlyGraph)
               {
                @:{device: '@item.Hour.ToString("D2"):00', geekbench:@item.Sales },
               }
            ],
            xkey: 'device',
            ykeys: ['geekbench'],
            labels: ['Sold'],
            barRatio: 0.4,
            barColors: ['#0A4D70', '#34495E', '#ACADAC', '#3498DB'],
            xLabelAngle: 35,
            hideHover: 'auto',
            resize: true
      });
```

The onclick event looks like this:

```
$('.convertTimeZone').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post("/GeoTargeting/FetchTimeZone",{timeZone: "timeZone"}).done(function(data){

            hourlyGraph.redraw();
            $(window).trigger('resize');
        });
    });
```

This is the part that doesn't works:

```
  hourlyGraph.redraw();
  $(window).trigger('resize');
```

I need to somehow now just redraw the graph after the post is done and display it on my View... But I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here... Can someone help me out ?

Comment: Anyone guys? =) Maybe I should return the view instead of Json ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is returning json (and the only thing in the response is `"OK"` - it does not contain any data that could be used to update your chart). There is no point setting `ViewBag` properties unless you return a view (and the view is using those values).

Your method should either

1. Return a partial view containing the html for a new graph based on
   the values of `hourlyData` and in the `success` callbacl of your
   `$.post()` function, update the DOM by replacing the existing graph,
   or
2. Return json containing the data for updating the graph, for example
   `var data = hourlyData.Select(x => new { device = x.Hour.ToString(...), geekbench = x.Sales }); return Json(data);` so
   that in the `success` callback, you can the update the data in the graph (e.g. using `hourlyGraph.setData(data);`)